Authentication Failed, 401 Unauthorized error in GH Actions
I am trying to publish Maven artifacts to GitHub Packages through GitHub Actions. The following is my first attempt where I have used the same file that GitHub suggests with the only changes being the on and if condition.
name: Continuous Deployment

run-name: Deploying to GitHub Packages

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]
    types: closed
    paths: folder/pom.xml

jobs:

  deploy:

    if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.merged }}

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup the JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '21'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: maven
      
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Packages
        run: mvn -B deploy -f folder/pom.xml
        env:
          PUSH_TO_PACKAGES: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Next, I tried using a GitHub PAT (classic) with write privileges for Packages (read for packages and all for repo are ticked by default). Instead of the permissions section, I added the following:
env:
      PUSH_TO_PACKAGES: ${{ secrets.PUSH_TO_PACKAGES }}

and removed the GITHUB_TOKEN at the end of the file. Both files give the same error. When I manually mvn deploy'ed from my PC, the package was uploaded as expected. I placed the above line right after the last run command as well. But neither of the three methods worked.
I looked multiple discussions on both GitHub and Stack Overflow but they all had the error only with one of the tokens. For me, both the default and Personal Access tokens are failing.
